# Showing that $R^2$ has no countable basis in a given topology

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the following question:

[image]

I was able to do parts (a) and (b) (whilst (b) was beyond tedious to consider all the different cases, but I am stuck on part (c). What I am stuck on is showing that no countable basis exists. I can make myself specific examples and show that they don't work, however, I do not know how to argue that no countable basis exists. This is 100 per cent a contradiction argument but I can't imidietetly see how one will argue that a countable basis implies that $R^2$ is countable. I tried diagonal arguments but to no avail. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you found (b) tedious - I think that for this question it's fine to assume $<$ is a total order. Then $B_1 \cap B_2$ will always also belong to the basis, because $\langle \mathbf x_1, \mathbf y_1 \rangle \cap \langle \mathbf x_2, \mathbf y_2 \rangle = \langle \max\{\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2\}, \min\{\mathbf y_1, \mathbf y_2\} \rangle$. In general this space is fairly analogous to $\Bbb R$ - if you repeat this construction on $\Bbb R$ with the normal order, you get the Euclidean topology. In some sense this space is "longer" though - which is why second countability fails.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen when doing the question I had that we had to consider each possibility for the components $x_1$ and $x_2$. Could you elaborate on your max notation for vectors?

Comment: By "$\max\{\mathbf a, \mathbf b\}$", I mean "whichever one of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ is larger with respect to $<$". The point is that for any $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, we either have $\mathbf a = \mathbf b$, or $\mathbf a < \mathbf b$, or $\mathbf a > \mathbf b$, and also if $\mathbf x < \mathbf y$ and $\mathbf y < \mathbf z$, then $\mathbf x < \mathbf z$. So $<$ is a "total order". I think you wouldn't need much justification in the exam - it's a fairly straightforward fact about the dictionary order. This whole construction works just as well in any totally ordered set!